# Using vim for indentation in C++

Tags: vim

I use vim to write code (please , lets not discuss why) . We indent our code using a common vimrc

```
syntax on        "Turn on syntax highlighting
set laststatus=2 "Always show status line

set tabstop=4    "Number of spaces a TAB in the text stands for

...<more code>...

""Converting tabs to spaces
set expandtab
set tags=./tags;/
map <C-\> :vsp <CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
```

This however is missing code to remove extra white space in between the 2 words and removing wrong spaces before comma etc .

Does anyone has any suggestion to remove those white spaces as well ?

Is there some standard that is followed which can help me as a guide to format c++ code ?

Answer (score 2):

Vim is the wrong tool for what you want, since it doesn't know, nor care, about C++ syntax.  Try a source code beautifier instead, such as [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) or [GNU indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/).

Comment: Indeed. Vim is a great *editor*, but if you want to *fix* code that you *edited wrongly*, a beautifier is the correct answer. You can always bind a call to a beautifier to a Vim key mapping.

Comment: Does these solve the spacing issue as well . like space between dots and extra spaces before ,

Comment: @MAG: Typically code beautifiers have many options, and it depends on how you configure them.  But normally, yes, all beautifiers should be able to fix spacing.